# ASP.NET + C# -- Exporting Crystal Report to PDF -- Error + Upgrade Needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports

I'm maintaining a multi-project solution in ASP.NET + C#. We've decided to upgrade to .NET Framework 3.5 and ASP.NET 2.0. One of the last issues with the upgrade is with Crystal Reports.

I'm getting the following error:

> Method
>   'ISCREditableRTFExportFormatOptions_reserved5'
>   on type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.EditableRTFExportFormatOptionsClass'
>   from assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel,
>   Version=11.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' is
>   overriding a method that has been
>   overridden.

**which is described:** http://www.trinet.co.uk/support/kb.aspx?kbid=000043

They suggest that I upgrade crystal reports to version R2.

What exactly does this mean? Do I just need to package different DLL's in my bin folders? Or do I need to uninstall and install the new version of Crystal Reports software on the test & production servers?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#09

It is necessary to install the Crystal Runtime on developer and deployment servers. The following is the name of the download to use for x86 machines: Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 x86 Redistributable Package (32 bit)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the update needs to be installed.  There should be instructions that come with the update.